# Mock a non-default function using Jest and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

In a test file I need to render a component while mocking out some of its sub components. The file structure would look loosely something like this.

File 1

```
import {A, B} from 'a-module';

export function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <div>
            <A /> // I need to mock
            <B /> // these components out
        </div>
    );
}
```

File 2

```
import {MyComponent} from 'File 1';

/*
 * In this file I would like to render MyComponent but
 * have components A and B be replaced by mocks
 */
```

I have tried doing `jest.mock('a-module', () => 'Blah');` but this is not successfully mocking the components. This works however when using default imports in File 1.

Any help in mocking out components `A` and `B` when rendering `MyComponent` in file 2 would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You can mock non defaults like this:**

```
jest.mock('a-module', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => 'Blah',
  A: () => 'Blah',
  B: () => 'Blah'
}));
```

https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/06/28/jest-mock-default-named-export/

**or use __mocks__**

as an alternative you could create a file under `__mocks__` folder next to the original module with the same name as the module:

```
a_module_folder > 
    a-module.js
    __mocks__ >
        a-module.js
```

and that mock should just export the mocked versions:

```
export const A = () => 'Blah';
export const B = () => 'Blah';
```

and then just mock like this:

jest.mock('a-module');

for node_modules just put `__mocks__`folder on the same level as `node_modules`

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

Comment: Do you have any further insight on why we need to set __esModule? It seems to work without that option.

Comment: I think it is required only if you also need to mock the default export.
see https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/a169b279097b0275209da1bdd1146a6d1ee884fa/packages/jest-worker/src/workers/threadChild.js

Answer (score 3):

Testing React components is mostly done with Enzyme, if you are trying to do it only with Jest you have probably picked the wrong tool. I can only guess why you need to mock a component, but most surely you will be able to achieve it with Enzyme.

There is **Enzyme shallow rendering** which is specifically created for testing React. Jest itself is not capable of rendering components. The definition as per [Airbnb docs](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) is:

> Shallow rendering is useful to constrain yourself to **testing a component as a unit**, and to ensure that your tests aren't indirectly asserting on behaviour of child components.

Simply said it is going to render the tested component 1 level deep e.g.

```
// File2.js

import { MyComponent } from 'File1';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('should render shallowly my component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    console.log(wrapper.debug()); 
    // output:
    //   <div>
    //     <A />
    //     <B />
    //   </div>
    // Note: even if component <A /> is consisting of some markup, 
    // it won't be rendered 
  });
});
```

Essentially you don't need to mock any of its dependent components, these are already mocked with enzyme `shallow()`

What you can do instead is test when you pass certain props to `<MyComponent />`, dependent components `<A />` and `<B />` are receiving expected props.

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent foo={1} bar={2} />);
expect(wrapper.find('A').props().foo).toEqual(1);
expect(wrapper.find('B').props().bar).toEqual(2);
```

Comment: I would advise against using enzyme for testing as it encourages coupling the test to the implementation details. Check react-testing-library

Comment: What you should test is the component input and output. Like you say, you need to check if an element is a button (html button), but you should never need to know what react component was used inside, what internal state there is, etc. And Enzyme provides and encourages methods to test based on react component name (find) and to check internal state. That's what I meant by implementation details. The issue with testing those would be changes to implementation that do not change the output breaking the test, and worse, changes that actually break the output but still pass the test.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer and it will make me think again if I should be using enzyme but it doesnt directly answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a react component which is not default export which is actually a [good practice (since default exports should be avoided)](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/defaultisbad):

```
export function MyComponentX() {
    return (
        <div>...</div>
    );
}
```

You can mock it in jest easily:

```
jest.mock('path/to/MyComponentX', () => ({
  MyComponentX: () => <>MOCK_MY_COMPONENT_X</>,
}));
```