# Difficulty understanding mocked Jest functions

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a test file to test a React component.

The React component uses some helper functions to calculate some things, e.g. takes in a customer's date of birth and returns a number based on if their age is in a certain range.

In the test file, I am passing these values in so the test will pass for today, but I need to mock it so that always passes.

I understand that I need to mock the helper function that is being imported in the component, but I just can't figure this out.

A component code example is

```
import { ageFunc } from './mydir/helper/ageFunc';
```

Then it's used with some props passed into the component:

```
const ageRange value = ageFunc(customerPropValues);
```

This ageRange value then decides whether to render something or not.

In the test file I am passing valid customer birthdate values, to trigger the rendering behaviour I expect. How do I set this up with mocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood it entirely, but *if* you need to mock it so it always work, you should mock the implementation so it always returns the same thing. You can find out a lot about mocking custom functions [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#custom-matchers).

```
// Mock before importing
jest.mock('./mydir/helper/ageFunc', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => 'Default',
  ageFunc : () => 'hardcoded result',
}));
import { ageFunc } from './mydir/helper/ageFunc';

const ageRange = ageFunc(customerPropValues); // ageRange returns 'Hardcode result'
```

If this is not the case, you want, but just want to check whether the right arguments are being passed, or the right result is received, you can do some of the following:

```
// The mock function was called at least once
expect(ageFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();

// The mock function was called at least once with the specified arguments
expect(ageFunc).toHaveBeenCalledWith(arg1, arg2);

// The last call to the mock function was called with the specified arguments
expect(ageFunc).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(arg1, arg2);

// All calls and the name of the mock is written as a snapshot
expect(ageFunc).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Helpful links: [link #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602669/mock-a-non-default-function-using-jest-and-react) [link #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602669/mock-a-non-default-function-using-jest-and-react)

How does it work?

Let's start with a simple example of a default module:

`import a from './path'`

The way we would mock this would be:

```
jest.mock('./path')
import a from './path'
```

This the test file will read a mocked function into the `a` variable.

Now for your case you've got a named export, so the case is a bit more complex.

```
import { a } from './path'
```

To mock this, we have to extend `jest.mock` a bit.

```
jest.mock('./path', () => ({
      __esModule: true, // Settings to make it behave as an ECMAScript module
      default: () => 'Default', // Mock the default export (import a from './dir')
      a: () => 'hardcoded result', // Mock the named export (import { a } from './dir'
    }));
```

Comment: // Mock before importing
jest.mock('./mydir/helper/ageFunc')
import ageFunc from './mydir/helper/ageFunc';

ageFunc.mockImplementation(() => 'Hardcode result')); 

This didn't work, I'm using typescript and it complains that 'mockImplementation isn't a property of ageFunc.

Comment: That is the kind of thing I am looking for though.

Comment: @jobe sorry, I didn't notice it was a named export. I updated the code so it can work for `{ ageFunc }`

Comment: Thanks so much that worked! would you be kind enough to just explain the steps happening here and how it was mocked and used, I really want to get my head around understanding this. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps if you find a good article or link for this, as the ones I found were hard to follow and a bit deep.

Comment: @jobe I've added explanation and helpful links. Hope this can get you somewhere. Could you mark the answer as correct, if it is so?

Comment: Sure, will do. One follow up if you know, is it possible to mock this with 2 different values, I have one large describe with many it blocks, in one I want to set 1 value and in the other a different one. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @jobe It is most definitely possible, Take a look at this article: https://medium.com/trabe/mocking-different-values-for-the-same-module-using-jest-a7b8d358d78b

Comment: It seems in the last example they are using 2 describe blocks, I'd like to use 2 it blocks.